# Database Schema for Maintaining Phone Contacts of users

Tags: database-design

I was building an Application where I need to sync user's phone contacts. Now since a phone contact in user's phonebook have N different fields, such as `name`, `contact`, `work contact`, `email`, `email2`, `website` and various other fields.

Now, lets suppose I (User1) have a friend with name N1 having phone numbers P1 and P2 with emails E1 and E2. Now another user (User2) having the contact of the same user but with different name N2 having phone only P1 and email E1.

Currently I was thinking about the following schema

```
Contacts
--id
--phone
--email
--website
--address

UserContacts
--userid
--contacts(list of contacts)
```

I need to make sure that the details that User1 has of friend should not be shared with User2, because User1 has P1P2 both and E1E2 both but User2 has only P1E1. Also, the name will be same across all the users, which is obviously not required.

Hence, now I was thinking to dump every contact of every user into the table,ie having duplicates. I'm using mongDB hence I dont mind having duplicates, but still I would like to know that how can I prevent data redundancy thereby also making sure that the information is not shared by the other users.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean that different users of your application risk that their phonebooks contacts are mixed up if they happen to have a contact with the same name? This looks like a terrible design to me.

Comment: *If they happen to have a contact with the same phone number. I know its a bad design, hence I thought of dumping every contact of the user as a separate entity, without caring about the data redundancy part. But I was wondering if there's any way I could prevent data redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to consider a contact (identified by a phone number) as a single object, and share this object amongst users which happen to have the same person in their addressbook. This is a terrible idea as if one user modifies the contact in his addressbook, the changes propagate to other users' addressbooks.

The proper way to do this is to consider every entry in a user's addressbook as an object:

```
Contacts
--------
id (PK)
name
address
phonenum
email
website
```

**Never** use a name (as it might be not unique in the DB) or a phone number (as it might change) as PK. A golden rule is to use non-meaningful fields such as an integer ID with autoincrement.

Note that this simple schema allows you to enter only one phone number or email for contact. For more flexibility you should move these attributes to their own table:

```
Phonenum
--------
id (FK)(PK)   id of the contact to which this phone number belongs
label (PK)    e.g. "Work", "Home", etc.
phonenum      e.g. "555-8765"
```

and the same for the email address.

This schema only modelizes the contacts. You'll have to implement a different table to store the data for the users of your application and bind the contacts (the first table above) included in a user's addressbook to the correct user.

Comment: So you mean to say that I should have a different object for the same contact in different user's phonebook.?

Comment: Yes. Unless the users of your app are all in the same organization, and an user's phonebook is a subset of the organization's public list of people (contacts), and each user has read-only access to the contacts. Then it would have sense to share the same contact. That's the only special case I can think of at this moment.